# libvirt kvm cpu/memory stats collection

Tags: linux, kvm, monitoring, libvirt

We are running virtual machines in kvm and i am trying to collect metrics and send it to influxdb + grafana for graphing.

I can see CPU stats using `virsh` but its in `time` in second spend, how do i convert this value in proper usage in `%` or human readable metrics?

```
[root@kvm01 ~]# virsh cpu-stats --total instance-0000047a
Total:
    cpu_time     160808730.755660547 seconds
    user_time       148000.880000000 seconds
    system_time   85012531.050000000 seconds
```

Comment: Collect data from inside VM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculating a CPU percentage is dependent on the time window you are looking at. So if you call `virsh cpu-stats` once, then call it again 10 seconds later, you would do need to do something like:

`(cpu_time2 - cpu_time1) / (10 * vcpus)`

That will tell you what percentage of the total time window the VM CPUs were running in.